# Is it OK to Use Dropbox in a Web Installer?

Tags: c#, installer

So I'm working in a modding project and they gave me the installing part as to do. We plan to publish it between **30 Aug. - 01 Sept.**

**My question is;** is it logical to use **Dropbox** to download files in the **web installer**? I saw Dropbox's public folder has **10 GB download bandwith** limit daily, after reaching that; they lock the account. I can insert a quota function and can use more than one Dropbox accounts. But it seems (not sure but) it's illegal or opposite to company's politics.

I don't know is the same bandwith limit applies to downloading directly from the **root folder.**
Also total size of the packages reaches **1 GB**. This why I'm afraid of the bandwith limit.

And, if you **don't recommend** using Dropbox, what would you advise? I think a simple web automator with **Mediafire** is a good choice but resuming download will **not be** possible. Also I have a **Fileserve Premium Account** (a friend of mine gave as a gift) but most probably it will be banned after using different IP's at the same time.

One more thing I'm writing it in **C#**.

Thanks...

Comment: using Dropbox in this way would be an insult to every Dropbox user depending on the size of the target crowd.  Were talking about 5 people downloading it or thousands?  I guarantee your account would be locked if you tried to use it for 1000s of downloads.

Comment: Must work for Dropbox eh? Dropbox cant get their own security sorted so I doubt they have a process in place to curtail downloads if you remain under the 10gb limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Dropbox would like that, even if you could technically get away with it. It's probably forbidden in their terms of use.

What kind of mod project is it? If it's moderately good, you can get free hosting at [Revora](http://www.revora.net/hosting).

*Disclaimer: I'm in that site's staff.*

Answer (score 8):

That really depends who "they" are. It seems unproffesional and penny pinching to use a consumer site like that. If you are only distributing it to other colligues then its fine but i wouldent use it to give to customers.

You can get ftp hosting for a pittance. Thats what i would use. Its faster with no limits on download (depending on how much you pay) and the file will stay there till you remove it.

Comment: Yes it's something unproffesional. I/They don't want to pay just for this project. Maybe we can do it after registering a domain. But the problem is, free web-hosts are too slow and unreliable.

Comment: PythEch : i would just spend the ~£8pcm on the hosting. Just your time discussing it now is worth more than that :) These people do a free trial if you could use http://www.iweb-ftp.co.uk/

Comment: how about using SkyDrive?

Comment: It seems it downloads without logging in. 100 Mb file size limit is annoying but it's not a big disadvantage in this project.

Answer (score 5):

If I was baking something into an installer, I would make sure the installer pointed towards a URL I had absolute control over even if the url redirected to dropbox or wherever.

Comment: So what you recommend? You say use a free webhost? There is a Dropbox API written in C#. But didn't test is resuming downloads possible.

Comment: No, I said a URL you had control over -- ie, on a domain you own. From there it could redirect to just about anywhere -- dropbox, s3, pluto, etc.

Answer (score 3):

For $20/month, you can get a VPS that will provide [200GB of transfer](http://www.linode.com/).  I'm sure if you shop around you can find even cheaper prices for that.  Or, you might investigate something like Amazon, where you pay based on what you use.  There's no reason to abuse a free service.

Answer (score 1):

It's too risky, I'd recommend stumping up a bit of cash and getting a proper download server. Dropbox do frown on multiple accounts and people exploiting their bandwidth, plus it's got so many attached risks that you'd spend more time working round it than it'd cost to get a server for a month.